# count over conditions with Dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, count

My problem is pretty straightforward , I have the following line:

> df_Return[df_Return['Aural'] >0].count()

Where df_return is a dataframe with only one column of float64 between -1 and 1,

I have the following error when I try to evaluate it:

```
Boolean array expected for the condition, not float64
```

Is there is something I am missing somewhere ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to *count* the elements above 0, you actually sum up the `True` values. Count would give you the number of elements in your DataFrame/Series.

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100))
(df > 0).sum()
# e.g. 51
(df > 0).count()
# 100 elements
```

For your given example, I would assume this code will work:

```
(df_Return['Aural'] > 0).sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have a version of `pandas` package that has a bug according to these issues:

https://github.com/quantopian/zipline/issues/2390

https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17170

You can try to upgrade your `pandas` package using the following commands:

```
pip install --upgrade pandas

conda update pandas (if you work in Anaconda environment)
```

Reproducing your approach using `pandas` 0.23.4 version:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

print(pd.__version__)
# 0.23.4

df_return = pd.DataFrame(data=np.linspace(-1, 1, 100), columns=['Aural'])
print(df_return.head())
#       Aural
# 0 -1.000000
# 1 -0.979798
# 2 -0.959596
# 3 -0.939394
# 4 -0.919192

cnt = df_return[df_return['Aural'] > 0].count()
print(cnt['Aural'])
# 50
```